# Convergence of vectors

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Recently I've read a paper and there is one moment I cannot fully realise on my own. It states as follows.

There is a vector of estimates $\hat{\mathbf{X}} = (\hat{X}_1, \dots, \hat{X}_N)$ (N is finite), and we're supposed to prove its convergence in distribution to multivariate normal distribution. The author has proven that the following holds (as $n \to \infty$):
$$
\sqrt{n} \begin{pmatrix} \hat{X}_i \\ \hat{X}_j \end{pmatrix} \overset{d}{\to} N \left(0, \left( \begin{matrix} q_{ii} & q_{ij} \\ q_{ji} & q_{jj} \end{matrix} \right) \right),
$$
because the vector of the couple of variables (well, technically, processes) itself converges to a slightly different version of normal distribution (with the use of CLT). This part is pretty clear, but after stating that he concludes that we can apply the method of empirical processes that, in its turn, implies that
$$
\sqrt{n} \hat{\mathbf{X}}\overset{d}{\to} N \left(0, Q \right),
$$
where $Q$ is $N \times N$ matrix with, as you might've guessed, the very same $q_{ij}$-s.

How is it possible? Is there any paper I can read to clarify the issue? Please do not refer me to some empirical processes book, I have no idea what it has to do with all of this.

Thanks for any help.